# updating hdf5 data on simple calibration

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to update hdf5 file data which needs calibration.
The code which I have added is:

```
with h5py.File(fileName,'r+') as hf:
    keys=hf.keys()
    data = hf[key][...]
    hf[key][...] = data*calibration_factor
```

Just for the simple calibration. However, its resulting to all zero in `hf[key][...]`. When I am assigning the product on the right side to a variable, I am getting the result properly. The `dtype` of `data` is `int16`. Any possible solution for this? I am struggling a lot on this,thanks for understanding.

This question I have posted as an add-on to another question, but as its separate hence created a new question here. Please don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of `data`?  Some sample values of `data` and `calibration_factor` might also help us see what's going on.  I suspect you are trying to write a float value back to an integer dataset.

Comment: ipdb> type(data)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
ipdb> np.shape(data)
(2480000,)
ipdb> ipdb> p data[0:200]
array([-1,  4,  0,  0,  0, -1,  5,  0,  0,  2,  4,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,
        0,  0,  5,  0, -1,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  4, -3, -1,  0, -2,  2,  4,
        0,  0,  6,  0, -3,  4, -3, -2, -7, -7, -1,  4, -5,  0, -3, -1,  0,
        0,  3,  0, -2, -2, -8, -5, -1,  3,  0,  6,  0, -1,  6, -2, -3,  0,
       -1,  3,  0,  3,  0, -6, -1], dtype=int16)
ipdb> 
ipdb> p calibration_factor
0.015151515
ipdb>

Comment: See the `dtype=int16`?  The calibrated value will be small, which when written back to the integer `dataset` will be truncated to 0.

Comment: but then when I give g=data*calibration_factor, I get proper data. I am a bit lost how to fix this. Even when I try:ipdb> hf[key][...]=float(np.ravel(data))*calibration_factor
*** TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: You don't understand.  `hf['key']` dataset can only hold integers.  It doesn't matter what is on the RHS of the assignment.  Ravel, float and all kinds of random dancing around isn't going to help you.  You'll have to create a new `dataset`, one that has a float `dtype` if you want to store the float values.

Comment: The question would be complete only if you include some simple statements in which you write something to the file. Currently it remains just guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `np.asarray(data, dtype=float)`.

Based on yours and @hpaulj comment, your result is being truncated to 0 because data is `int16`.

Comment: Nopes, I tried it before: data = float(hf[key][...])
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: I tried data=np.asarray(data, dtype=float), still all zero for hf[key][...], final code like:data=np.asarray(data, dtype=float)
                    hf[key][...] = data*calibration_factor

Comment: The truncation is in the storage step, not the calculation  before that.

Answer (score 0):

In HDF5 files, datasets have a datatype that is fixed when the dataset is created.

As hpaulj mentions, at the line

```
hf[key][...] = data*calibration_factor
```

the values on the right-hand side (which are correctly promoted to floating point values) are rounded to integers when *storing* them in the dataset.

If you want to store the normalized values, you must create a new dataset (with the same name, after removing the old one) that will have the appropriate datatype.

I propose the following:

```
with h5py.File(fileName,'r+') as hf:
    keys=hf.keys()
    data = hf[key][...]
    del hf[key]
    hf[key] = data*calibration_factor
```

which should store the result as floating point values. The code does not define `key`, but I guess the example you gave is simplified with respect to the actual code.